# toString method in Java benefits

Tags: java, string, object, overriding, tostring

What is the benefit in using toString method in java if it has always need to be overridden?

Example:

```
String var = "3";
byte [] var_inBytes = var.getBytes();
String var2 = var_inBytes.toString();
```

this will give me the name of the object followed by the hash code
okay then when we can use toSting method without overriding?

Comment: For the same reason you might use it when you do override things -- to debug for instance. That class name will tell you the type of the object (not always the same as the variable) and the hashCode can tell you which instance of the object you're using, useful if you want to check if its the same instance as held by another variable elsewhere.

Comment: But in general, better to use the override, here `Arrays.toString(var_inBytes)`

Answer (score 0):

Every `Class` is **inherited** from `Object` Class in Java, Therefore the `Object` class methods are available to all Java classes.

According to the Java doc :

> In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually
>   represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses override this method.

You may want to override the default `toString()` method in your current class to represent a different format string depend on your requirement but since the `Object` class has this method, All of the other classes have a default `toString()` method.

You can read more here :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method is one of the programmer best friend. I use it on each business object or each entity at least, to list their variable members content.

At the time an unexpected problem occurs and that your are in big trouble, and especially if you are in emergency, it makes a great change if you can read : "*Big trouble on item {Id : 125, name : Smith, Address : 15 King Square}*", instead of "*Big trouble on an item*".
Not only you have the id you can use for your internal research, but you can also tell a end-user about who is really impacted : *Mr Smith*. May be your end-user will have a clue : "*Oh yes, we were doing special operation on him, because...*"

In plenty of logs, on `TRACE` or `DEBUG` level only of course, I dump many business object or entities content that way. If a really big problem happens, even in production, and that it is reproducible, I may (in the dire case) restart the application in `TRACE` mode and learn what really happens.

`toString()` is a life savior, I say.